Why is the power set of N uncountably infinite?
We know $N^k$ is countable for a fixed $k$.
We also know that the countable union of countable sets is countable.
The power set of $N$ is just $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} N^k$.
So why is the power set of $N$ not countable?
Similarly, why is the set of functions from $N$ to $N$ not countable, if there is a bijection between this set and $N^k$ for $k \rightarrow \infty$? Because if $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} N^k$ is countable, shouldn't $N^{\infty}$ also be countable?

power set of $N$ is not $\cup_k N^k$

$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} N^k$ is countable if it is all non-empty finite subsets of $\mathbb N$.  The problem comes with trying to count infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$, especially those with infinite complements

@Henry Ok, thanks. And what about the second question?

@Mark Your second question raises the same issue  "Can $k$ be infinite?" If not, then there is no bijection.

The first specific error you made is your statement "The power set of $\mathbb N$ is just $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb N^k$.
That's not true -- that's the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb N$. What about the set of prime numbers, for example? This is actually very similar to claiming that the set of real numbers is the union of all finite decimals -- whereas the uncountable majority of real numbers have infinite decimal expansions.
In your second statement, you're correct in saying that functions $\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ have a bijection to $\mathbb N^\infty$. However, $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb N^k$ does not mean that $\mathbb N^\infty$ is countable. Again, this is because the union is still composed of all finite sets.

Your mistake is in the second premise:

The power set of $\mathbb N$ is just $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb N^k$.

This is not true. For one, elements of $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb N^k$ are tuples, while the elements of the power set of $\mathbb N$ are subsets of $\mathbb N$.
Even if you would identify the tuple $(a_1, \dots, a_k)$ with the set $\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$, you still have infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ that are not accounted for. In other words, for which $k$ is the set of all even numbers an element of $\mathbb N^k$?
